# OpenXML for excel, foreach cell and row

Tags: excel, openxml

I have an excel file and the structure shown as following. The course cell is unlimited, may be one cell, may be ten cells. How can i get the current cell index and row index?

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, ..., ..., .......
ID, name, age, course1, course2, course3, course4..., course.......
1, peter, 14, Yes, null, No, null.....
2, tom, 20, No, Yes, null, null...
3, john, 30, Yes, null, no, null...

foreach (Cell c in cells) {
    //get the current cell index
    // if the c.header > D
    foreach (Row row in c.Elements<Row>())
        {
               //get the current row index
               //get the id value of current rowid
               //get the name value of current rowid
               //get the course value of current rowid
        }
}
```

Thanks.